# How to compile and use Intel esrt2 for chipset 62x driver on Ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, kernel, raid

Intel esrt2 is a raid system based on megasr which requires an out of tree kernel driver (no opensource alternatives). Intel [is publishing prebuilt kernel modules](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/29487/Intel-Embedded-Server-RAID-Technology-2-ESRT2-Linux-Treiber-f-r-Intel-Server-und-Systeme-die-auf-Intel-62x-Chipsatz-basieren-?product=99087) for Redhat and Suse as well as the source code for building it **on other distributions like Ubuntu in the current case** in the same archive file.

The problem is the source code does not come with any instructions on how to build it. No documentation, no source code kernel tree, no Makefile, no full scripts but just 3 folders and some C files

In such situation, how can I get esrt2 running without purschasing a costly license from RedHat or Suse?

Comment: Is there a `configure`, `INSTALL` or a `README*` file?

Comment: Going by https://cloudlinux.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115004561769-How-do-I-install-driver-for-LSI-MegaRAID-controller, I'd guess you'd have to do `sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)`; `cd` to one of the directories in `shim/library` and then run `make -C /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/ M=$PWD`

Comment: @muru that would require a Makefile un the `shim/library` folder so this doesn t works.

Comment: I said "one of the directories in `shim/library`, not `shim/library` itself. Those subdirectories do have Makefiles.

Comment: @waltinator that s the point no. Except for the README which states the `shim` folders is for other Linux distributions.

Comment: @muru the instructions in the article you linked works because it for red had. `shim/library` subdirectories contains precompiled `library.a` files for Suse and Red hat kernel configurations. Not for Ubuntu.

Comment: @user2284570 sure, but those do work for close enough kernel versions (e.g., the `rhel7-64` one builds in Ubuntu 13.10). The library in `rhel8-64` turns out to be corrupted in the archive I downloaded, so you might consider asking them to provide a not-corrupted one that you can use with a newer Ubuntu (RHEL 8 is 4.18, so you might be able to get Ubuntu 18.04 working with that).

Comment: @muru for the other `rhel-8` it s just the format being too recent for Ubuntu linker. Red Hat kernels have lot of differrent compile time constants compared to allmodules Debian and thus Ubuntu kernels. Yes as it s precompiled, linking into a kernel module works without errors, but if you try to force insert it, it will crash because of data structures mismatch in0n symbols. Additionnally, because I m using other recent hardware, I m needing a 5.x kernel whearas Intel only supports 4.x.